# Does compiling to javascript preclude dart adding weak references?

Tags: javascript, dart

I'm disappointed that dart doesn't feature weak references.

Is there something about compiling to a language which doesn't offer weak references which makes it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In order to support weak references, you need a way to interact with or override the GC.
That is fundamentally impossible in Javascript.

Comment: i'm not convinced. in the end, js is turing complete - as an extreme approach to supporting weak references, one could write a vm in js which implements memory management itself.

Comment: True.  I should have said that it's impossible to do that within the JS host environment.

Answer (score 1):

Dart wants to compile to *performant* JavaScript. That's why it needs to skip certain features (tail calls, for example). And I'd even argue that weak references are a bad idea anyway.

Comment: what do you dislike about weak references? i'd like to have them so that i can build an event system which doesn't easily lead to memory leaks. if event triggers could weakly reference their callbacks, this would be easier than diligently unbinding those triggers.